# Nested variables in Symfony .env

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I need to use nested variables in Symfony's `.env` file. I tried this:

```
# .env
DIRECTORY=my_bucket
PREFIX_URI='cdn.example.com/%env(DIRECTORY)%'
```

Then I need to use `PREFIX_URI` in a `.yaml` configuration file in `config/packages`:

```
vich_uploader:
  mappings:
    fs_name:
      uri_prefix: '%env(PREFIX_URI)%'
```

This doesn't seem to work however. The variables are just ignored. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `.env` file is not using PHP. The correct way to reference another variable is like this:

```
DIRECTORY=my_bucket
PREFIX_URI="cdn.example.com/${DIRECTORY}"
```

Comment: So in your example, `DIRECTORY` doesn't have to be an environment variable, right? Just be defined in this file, right?

Comment: I had also tried your way before posting this question, but using apostrophes, not double quotes. I think that was the problem, because I was using the same syntax you describe. However, it works. Thank you very much!